# Typescript interface gets wrong property type when using as operator

Tags: typescript

Since I am new to typescript I am not sure how the following code works, and why it is not typesafe:

```js
interface MyNumber {
    x: number;
}

let data = JSON.parse(
    `{
        "x": "Hello"
    }`
);

let number: MyNumber = data as MyNumber ;
console.log(typeof number.x);
```

Webstorm tells me that x is of type number, but console prints type string.
How can this be since the interface clearly defined the type of x as number not as string?

How would I do this correctly, to get a typesafe object (with the correct type?)

This question was derived from a more practical code like:

```js
app.post('/', (req: Request<{},{}, Person>, res: Response) => {
   req.body.age; // <-- also can be either string or number depending what I provide in the body, so no typesafety
}
```

Comment: Typescript types are only a compile type construct. When you use `as` you are basically telling the compiler you know the true type of something, and typescript will take your workd for it. the `as` operator has no runtime conversion behavior

Comment: `as` is a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). TypeScript **does not** exist at runtime, the types are stripped in transpilation.

Comment: Ok, but then I don't get typescript, yet. I am able to define types using the typesystem, but cannot be sure that this will work out (is safe) since a number at design time still can be a string at runtime, or is this only true for the type-assertion construct? Sorry for this maybe dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the use of typescript.
Obviously your editor says the variable is of type number as defined by the typescript code.
The content then is parsed at run time, so you will have no errors in your ide but during execution the resulting javascript has the content unchanged, i.e. as a string.